# creating a python number guessing game

Tags: python

SUPER new to programming so bear with me, please. I am taking my first ever programming class and for a project, I was given a list of requirements I need to fulfill, creating a simple number guessing game has been the only thing I've not had a lot of trouble with so I decided to give it a go.
(i need 1 class, function, dictionary or list, for loop, and while loop) What I, well at least have tried to make is a guessing game that gives a limit of 2 guesss for a # between 0 and 10, any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
    import random 

class Player:
  player = ""
  playerscore = 0

  def gamestart(self):
    self.number = random.randint(0,7)
    self.guesss = 0
    self.list = []
    self.limit = 3
    print()
    print("Guess what number I'm thinking off")
    print()
    print("Might even give you a hit if you do well enough")
    print()

    while self.limit > 0:
      self.player_guess = int(input("Well? What are you waiting for? Start guessing:"))
      print()

      if self.player_guess > 7 or self.player_guess < 0:
        print("Wow that was a terrible guess, think harder or we might be here all week long")
        print("also,", self.player_guess , "is not in the range...")
        print("Becareful though, you only have", self.limit, "guesss left")
        
      elif self.player_guess > self.number:
        self.guesss += 1
        self.limit-= 1
        print("WRONG")
        print(self.player, "You only have", self.limit, "guesss left")
        self.list.append(self.player_guess)
        
      elif self.player_guess < self.number:
        self.guesss += 1
        self.limit -= 1 
        print("oh oh... wrong again!")
        print()
        print(self.player, "You only have", self.limit, "guesss left.")
        self.list.append(self.player_guess)
        
      else:
        self.limit -= 1
        self.playerscore += 1
        self.list.append(self.player_guess)
        print()
        print("wow, you actually got it right")
        print()
        print(self.player_guess, "IS THE CORRECT ANSWER!")
        print()
        print("you only had",self.limit,"left too...")
        print("Lets see all the numbers you guessed")
        print()
        
        for i in self.list:
          print(i)
        self.list.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the question confusing, however the following code should work as a number guessing game, hope I answered your question.

```
import random
game = "true"
guesses = 2
while game == "true":
    comp_number = int(random.uniform(1,8))
    print("I have randomly selected a number between 1 and 7 (inclusive), you have 2 attempts to guess the number.")
    while guesses > 0:
        if guesses == 2:
            turn = "first"
        else:
            turn = "final"
        guess = int(input("Please submit your "+turn+" guess:"))
        while guess < 1 or guess > 7:
            print("Invalid guess, remember my number is between 1 and 7 (inclusive)")
            guess = int(input("Resubmit a valid guess:"))
        if guess == comp_number:
            print("Congratulations you guessed my number, you win!")
            if str(input("Would you like to play again? Please enter Y or N.")) == "Y":
                guesses = 2
                game = "true"
            else:
                game = "false"
                break
        else:
            print("Incorrect number, try again.")
            guesses -= 1
    print("You where unable to guess my number, I win!")
    if str(input("Would you like to play again? Please enter Y or N.")) == "Y":
        guesses = 2
        game = "true"
    else:
        game = "false"
        break
```